# Order by instr in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, sql-order-by

I need to order a query in a particular way according to search criteria. I have the ordering of the search working for db2 but I also need to get it working for Oracle.

My query for db2 uses the locate function.

```
Select   *
from     <table>
where    UPPER(NAME) like "'%<search>%'
order by locate('<search>', UPPER(NAME)),
         UPPER(NAME)
```

This would return a search of review as:

Review,
Review A Task,
Review B Task,
Another Review

I have tried to use the instr function in oracle but it is not returning what I had hoped.

```
select   *
from     <table>
where    UPPER(name) like '%<search>%'
order by instr('<search>',UPPER(name)),
         name
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to get the order I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the parameters in the instr the wrong way round. You are currently looking for the pattern `UPPER(nane)` inside the search term. The following works for me:

```
with sample_data as (select 'Review' name from dual union all
                     select 'Review A Task' name from dual union all
                     select 'Review B Task' name from dual union all
                     select 'Another Review' name from dual)
select   *
from     sample_data
where    UPPER(name) like '%REVIEW%'
order by instr(UPPER(name), 'REVIEW'),
         name;

NAME          
--------------
Review        
Review A Task 
Review B Task 
Another Review
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should have looked at the function closer.